# Why are cardano-cli generated payment addresses shorter than those from Yoroi or Daedalus?

Tags: wallet, cardano-cli, address

Why are addresses generated by cardano-cli shorter than those generated by Yoroi or Daedalus?
The addresses produced by running

```
cardano-cli address build
```

are 58 characters including the "addr" prefix while those from Yoroi and Daedalus are 103 characters.
Are there any cases where these types of addresses are not interchangable?
Is there a way to get the cli to generate an address similar to Yoroi and Daedalus?
Thanks!
Shawn

Answer (score 2):

The first part is a 'payment address', which you're seeing on Yoroi and Daedalus combined with a 'staking address' (`cardano-cli stake-address build ...`).  If you look at your receiving addresses on those apps you will notice that they all end the same, indicating use of the same staking address for all of them (in the current implementations).

The Cardano-cli gives lower-level access to the finer details of Cardano operations than the wallets.

Comment: There seems to be a word missing between the first two words of your answer: "`The [?] is ...`"

Comment: thanks, I re-worded it

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to extend a payment address using [cardano-addresses](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-addresses) to get a similar one as generated by Yoroi or Daedalus.

See also `cardano-address address delegation --help` for an example.